# React Checkbox: Change in child cannot re-render parent node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm making checkboxes for my project and sadly I spent a day on it but still couldn't solve the problem. It has mother checkbox which controls all children checkboxes and children checkboxes.

What I wanted to make is, if all checkboxes in children get checked, parent node's allChecked checkbox has to be checked.
If any of the checkboxes get unchecked, parent node's allChecked checkbox has to be unchecked.

At first time, I thought maybe it's the problem of props. I give 'allChecked' value from 'cards' to 'card' and 'Do they give only the value as prop?(like true of false)'. But after some experiments and could find they share same variable.

I cannot understand why my code doesn't change parent node's checkbox when children's checkboxes fully checked. As far as I know, react re-render node when property get changed, but after changed, the checkbox in mother does not change.

Cards.js

```
const Cards = ({ cards }) => {
    const numberOfCards = cards.length;
    const [allChecked, setAllChecked] = useState(false);
    const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState(new Set());

    const handleAllChecked = () => {
        setAllChecked(!allChecked);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <>
                <>
                    <input type="checkbox" value={allChecked} onChange={handleAllChecked} />
                </>
                <>
                    { cards.map(el => <Card
                                    id={el.id}
                                    key={el.id}
                                    checkedList={checkedList}
                                    setCheckedList={setCheckedList}
                                    allChecked={allChecked}
                                    setAllChecked={setAllChecked}
                                    numberOfCards={numberOfCards}
                                />) }
                </>
            </>
        </>
    )
}
```

Card.js

```
const Card = ({ id, checkedList, setCheckedList, allChecked, setAllChecked, numberOfCards }) => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    const controlCheckedList = () => {
        if (!checked) {
            checkedList.add(id);
            setCheckedList(checkedList);
        } else {
            checkedList.delete(id);
            setCheckedList(checkedList);
        }
    }

    const handleChecked = () => {
        setChecked(!checked);
        controlCheckedList();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (allChecked) {
            setChecked(true);
            checkedList.add(id);
            setCheckedList(checkedList);
        }
        else if (!allChecked&&checkedList.size===numberOfCards) {
            setChecked(false);
            setCheckedList(new Set());
        };
    }, [allChecked]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (checked) {
            if (checkedList.size===numberOfCards){ // here is the part where I think mother's allChecked has to be changed
                setAllChecked(true);
            }
        } else {
            if (checkedList.size<numberOfCards){ // here is the part where I think mother's allChecked has to be changed
                setAllChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }, [checked]);

    return (
        <>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onChange={handleChecked} />
        </>
    )
}
```

I can feel there would be some easy way to solve it with ContextAPI or something, but really want to solve it with useState and useEffect(I could find many other example).
What I want to know is why when all checkboxes are checked, it doesn't make visible change on mother checkbox even the value of the mother checkbox is changed? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `checked` not `value` in **Cards.js**.

```js
<input type="checkbox" checked={allChecked} onChange={handleAllChecked} />
```